# Poincare inequality on the hemisphere

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, spherical-geometry

**Background:**

Let $\mathbb{S}^2_+$ be the hemisphere. Then we know that for $f:\mathbb{S}^2_+\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying (when written in coordinates) $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(r,\theta)\sin(r)dr d\theta = 0$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} |f|^2 \sin(r)drd\theta \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} |\nabla f|^2 \sin(r)drd\theta.$$

Here the best constant $1/2$ can be computed by simply recalling the first eigenvalue on the hemisphere (which is equal to two) along with fact that the poincare constant is $\frac{1}{\lambda_1(\mathbb{S}^2_+)}.$

**Question:**

I am interested in understanding the case when the test functions in the above inequality are of the form $f(r,\theta)=f(r)$. In particular if we work with $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(r)\sin(r)dr=0$ then what is the best constant $C>0$ in the inequality

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} |f|^2 \sin(r)dr \leq C \int_{0}^{\pi/2} |\partial_r f|^2 \sin(r)dr?$$

Comment: (i) "we know that [...]" -- How/from where do we know that? (ii) Shouldn't $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}$ be replaced everywhere by $\int_0^{\pi/2}$?

Comment: I agree with Iosif that $r$ should run on $[0, \pi/2]$. Also, if you show some details on the proof of the first statement, it will probably shed light on the second. It may well be that a maximizer to the first inequality is radial (i.e. it depends on $r$ only), in which case the second follows.

Comment: @IosifPinelis (i) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295683/sobolev-and-poincare-inequalities-on-compact-riemannian-manifolds might be relevant (ii) you are right, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I am guessing the extremizers are eigenfunctions on the hemisphere, which are the coordinate functions. Writing them co-ordinates, $x_1=\sin(r)cos(\theta),x_2=\sin(r)\sin(\theta).$ Then $\int \sin(r)^3 = 2/3$ while $\int \cos(r)^2 \sin(r) = 1/3$ so I am guessing that the constant has to be at least $2$?

Comment: Oh wait $\int \sin(r)^2\neq 0,$ maybe I am missing something here....